# Adding to a linked list in the right alphabetical position

Tags: java, linked-list

My assignment is to modify the below code so it positions new elements alphabetically in the linked list. It currently adds the element to the end of the list.

```
public void add(String element) {
    Node newNode = new Node(element);
    if (first == null)
        first = newNode;
    else {
        // Find the predecessor of the element to add
        Node current = first;
        Node prev = null;
        while (current != null) {
            prev = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        // New last element 
        if (current == null) 
            prev.next = newNode;
        else if (prev == null) {
            newNode.next = first;
            first = newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a reasonable task. Did you have a question?

Comment: That `else if` block will never happen. You can just do `prev.next = newNode;`

Comment: How would I sort the elements alphabetically? Do I use a compareTo method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to continue traversing the list until you reach a node that is alphabetically greater than the one you are inserting.

Figure out where in the code you are traversing over the linked list.

```
while (current != null) {
    prev = current;
    current = current.next;
}
```

Add a conditional comparing the *element* of the nodes.

```
while (current != null && current.data < newNode.data) {
```

Stop the traversal and add in your new node.

```
prev.next = newNode
newNode.next = current
```